# Displaying a PDF from the Blobstore

Tags: django, google-app-engine, blobstore

I have various PDF documents as blobs in the App Engine blobstore. Now, I want to preview them on a HTML page. From various other questions, I figured the HTML setup should be:

```
<embed src="{{ url_to_my_pdf_blob }}" width="500" height="600">
```

While experimenting, I found that in the SDK the `get_serving_url` function will not only work for images but will also work for PDF blobs. This approach unfortunately fails in production.

I looked at the example using `blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler` but could not figure out how to wire this to my view (my app is based on `Django`, the HTML file with the preview is served by a Django view class).

How do I get the url of the blob?

Comment: What do you mean by "fails in production"? I migrated my files to GCS, but before that I used the Blobstore, and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I mean it will not work when deployed to Google App Engine. It fails with a TransformationError (which is understandable as it is not an image but a PDF).

Comment: Did you try multiple inheritance? Or use GCS to create a serving url, without the image API.

Comment: Why would you use the Image API for PDF files? Do not use it, and the Blobstore will serve your PDFs with no problems.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I don't. I was just experimenting. As per my question, how do I get the url of the PDF???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a ServeHandler, as described here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Serving_a_blob

For examples of the implementation, see [Downloaded filename with Google App Engine Blobstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324895/downloaded-filename-with-google-app-engine-blobstore).